# Pervasive query super slow

Tags: pervasive

I really dont have any knowledge about pervasive database. We have one simple query which is running very slow (taking ages). I have created index on HiReqe (patientid,reqnum, reqdate), patient (patientid, patsex, patcob,patdob) and hitest (reqnum, testcode). Is there anything that i can do run query faster?

select a.reqnum, a.reqdate, b.patientid, b.patcob, b.patdob, b.patsex, c.testcode, c.normalresult from "HiReq" as a

inner join "Patient" as b on a.patientid = b.patientid and b.patsex = 'M'

inner join "Hitest" as c on a.reqnum = c.reqnum and c.testcode = '903'

Edit:  I was trying to create DSN as mentioned in document, but how can i store .QPF file? Am i missing anything?

[DSN Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX9uK.png)

Comment: A few questions.  What version of Pervasive are you using?  How long is "ages"?  A few seconds, a few minutes, a few hours?  How many records are in each table?  How many are returned?  Have you run a query plan?

Comment: We are using version 11.31. According to developer it was running for hours and they need to stop or kill the process. Each table contains million s of row. I am not sure about the query plan. How do i run that?

Comment: Here's a link to an old article about QUery Plan: http://mirtheil.com/files/queryplanviewer.pdf.   SHould all still apply.

Comment: Also, what tool is being used to run the query?  Have you tried something like ODBC Test or other query tool?

Comment: I am running the query though PCC itself.

Comment: I have created DSN setting but how can i store the query as a .QPF? Please check in Edit section : DSN setting.

Comment: You can use the SET QRYPLAN and SET QRYPLANOUTPUT commands in the PCC as documented at http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv12/sqlref/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=qpv.htm&single=true.